# How to get the text of span in javascript when the clientidmode is static of a asp.net page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using this

```
alert(spanid.innerHTML);
```

this shows the message undefined. why?

Comment: can you also add the assoc html

Answer (score 1):

you should get innerHTML the following way:

```
var htmlelement = document.getElementById('spanId');
alert( htmlelement.innerHTML);
```